# mongo operation speed : array $addToSet/$pull vs object $set/$unset

Tags: mongodb

I have a `index` collection containing lots of terms, and a field `items` containing identifier from an other collection. Currently that field store an array of document, and docs are added by `$addToSet`, but I have some performance issues. It seems an `$unset` operation is executed faster, so I plan to change the array of document to a document of embed documents.

Am I right to think the $set/$unset fields are fatest than push/pull embed document into arrays ?

**EDIT:**

> After small tests, we see the set/unset 4 times faster. On the other
>   hand, if I use object instead of array, it's a little harder to count
>   the number of properties (vs the length of the array), and we were
>   counting that a lot. But we can consider using `$set` everytime and
>   adding a field with the number of items.

This is a document of the current index :

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5594dea2b693fffd8e8b48d3"),
  "term": "clock",
  "nbItems": NumberLong("1"),
  "items": [
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("55857b10b693ff18948ca216"),
      "id": NumberLong("123")
    }
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("55857b10b693ff18948ca217"),
      "id": NumberLong("456")
    }
  ]
}
```

Frequent update operations are :
* remove item : `{$pull:{"items":{"id":123}}}`
* add item : `{$addToSet:{"items":{"_id":ObjectId("55857b10b693ff18948ca216"),"id":123,}}}`
* I can change `$addToSet` to `$push` and check duplicates before if performances are better

And this is what I plan to do:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5594dea2b693fffd8e8b48d3"),
  "term": "clock",
  "nbItems": NumberLong("1"),
  "items": {
    "123":{
      "_id": ObjectId("55857b10b693ff18948ca216")
    }
    "456":{
      "_id": ObjectId("55857b10b693ff18948ca217")
    }
  }
}
```

* remove item : `{$unset:{"items.123":true}`
* add item : `{$set:{"items.123":{"_id":ObjectId("55857b10b693ff18948ca216"),"id":123,}}}`

For information, theses operations are made with pymongo (or can be done with php if there is a good reason to), but I don't think this is relevant

Answer (score 1):

As with any performance question, there are a number of factors which can come into play with an issue like this, such as indexes, need to hit disk, etc.

That being said, I suspect you are likely correct that adding a new field or removing an old field from a MongoDB document will be slightly faster than appending/removing from an array as the array types will be less easy to traverse when searching for duplicates.

Comment: After some tests (on a really small set of documents), we see a 4 times faster process. but we will do tests on a bigger scale. On the other hand, if I use object instead of array, it's a little harder to count the number of properties (vs the length of the array). (I just edited my question adding that )

Comment: Thats correct. This would be the trade off for the performance increase